# getting div to expand to the height of it's contents

Tags: html, css

So I’m trying to redesign my website to keep the header at the top of the screen and let the rest of the page scroll beneath it.  I did some research and found a nice JSfiddle that explained what I needed to do: http://jsfiddle.net/austinbv/2KTFG

```css
#header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    background: green;
}
#body{ margin-top: 30px; height: 3000px; overflow: auto; }
```

```html
<div id='header'>hello</div>
<div id='body'>skdfl</div>
```

I added the 2 DIVs to a Dreamweaver template and then the CSS. I then broke my page up into 2 portions and placed each in the corresponding DIV.  Now when I view the page in the browser, the bottom div refuses to extend far enough to show the contents within. it stops at the bottom of the screen, not the bottom of the contents. See the example at http://www.rcda.org:81/index2.html

I researched the net and found people saying that the contents of the DIV are somehow floated and above the div causing the div to not expand. I did not float the contents.

What can I do to get body div to expand to the height of its contents?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.** NB - **Please don't abuse the code blocks to get around this requirement**.

Comment: To expand upon @Paulie_D, please post a) the HTML that shows your header and content to scroll, and b) the CSS you have so far.

Answer (score 2):

On your `div#body` (random div..), you have `overflow:hidden`- with a fixed height, this is hiding anything below the fixed height.

Answer (score 0):

Take off overflow: hidden; on the body css in index2.html

```
#body {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 203px;
}
```

Comment: If I do that then I get a scroll bar on the div next to the one on the page.

Comment: I then added scroll="no" to the body tag and set height on the div to 75% and it displayed properly. I now need to test on different monitors to see if 75% is correct to get the div to not go past the bottom of the window.

Comment: Actually the height should be 100% - 213px (header). I'm not sure if I can do that.

Comment: I just tried on an ipad and don't get the scroll bar on the div.

Comment: I got it working on ipad and the PC. Android is being funky and not letting me pinch zoom out to see the whole page. any ideas?